# List filtering using multiple classes/interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Basically I have a list of objects where each object might implement a different set of interfaces:

```
List<BaseObject> objects;

class BaseObject
{
  public void DoStuff();
}

interface IX
{
  void DoX();
}

interface IY
{
  void DoY();
}

interface IZ
{
  void DoZ();
}
```

And i would like to write something like this:

```
foreach(var obj in objects.OfType<BaseObject and IX>)
{
  obj.DoStuff();
  obj.DoX();
}
```

(E.g. i perform a specific algorithm for objects of type BaseObject and IX without having to do typecasts there)

Is it possible to do in C#?
What's the most elegant solution?

I can do this:

```
foreach(var obj in objects.OfType<IX>)
{
  var baseobj = (BaseObject)obj.DoStuff();
  obj.DoX();
}
```

But i find it ugly.

And I might need to apply specific operations to types that implement say interface IX and interface IZ.

```
foreach(var obj in objects.OfType<BaseType and IX and IZ>)
{
  obj.DoStuff();
  obj.DoX();
  obj.DoZ();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is to use `dynamic`:

```
foreach(var xz in objects.Where(o => o is IX && o is IZ).Select(o => (dynamic)o))
{
    xz.DoStuff();
    xz.DoX();
    xz.DoZ();   
}
```

Of course, you can still cast if you don't want to use `dynamic`:

```
foreach(var xz in objects.Where(o => o is IX && o is IZ))
{
    xz.DoStuff();
    ((IX)xz).DoX();
    ((IZ)xz).DoZ(); 
}
```

Comment: @JBeurer, yeah, it's a tradeoff :)

Answer (score 2):

With these classes and interfaces...

```
List<BaseObject> objects; 

class BaseObject 
{ 
  public void DoStuff(); 
} 

interface IX 
{ 
  public void DoX(); 
} 

interface IY 
{ 
  public void DoY(); 
} 

interface IZ 
{ 
  public void DoZ(); 
} 

class X : BaseObject, IX { }
class Y : BaseOjbect, IY { }
class Z : BaseObject, IZ {  }
class XY : BaseObject, IX, IY { }
```

Asumming you populate ojbect with any **Class** defined above

```
foreach (var o in objects)
{
  o.DoStuff();
  if (o is IX)
    ((IX)o).DoX(); //executed on class X and XY
  if (o is IY)
    ((IY)o).DoY(); //excuted on class Y and XY
  if (o is IZ)
    ((IZ)o).DoZ(); //excuted on class Z
}
```

That should do what you are looking for.

**UPDATED** per your comment.

```
foreach (var o in objects)
{
  o.DoStuff();
  if (o is IX and o is IY)
  {
    // do something different only for XY
  }
  else if (o is IX)
    ((IX)o).DoX(); //executed on class X 
  else if (o is IY)
    ((IY)o).DoY(); //excuted on class Y 
  else if (o is IZ)
    ((IZ)o).DoZ(); //excuted on class Z
}
```

**UPDATED** No type casting.

Requires another interface.  (Additionally, DoStuff() should be on all IX, IY, IZ).

```
interface IXY : IX, IY { }

//       This IXY could be var, but just strongly typing it for example
foreach (IXY o in objects.OfType(IXY)
                         .Cast<IXY>())
{
  o.DoStuff();
  o.DoX();
  o.DoY();
}
```

You could also do someting *CRAZY* like:

```
foreach (var obj in objects.OfType<IX>()
                           .OfType<IY>()
                           .OfType<IZ>()
                           .Select(o => new 
                                   {
                                      AsIX = (IX)o,
                                      AsIY = (IY)o,
                                      AsIZ = (IZ)o
                                   }) 
{  
    obj.AsIX.DoX();  
    obj.AsIY.DoY();  
    obj.AsIZ.DoZ();
}
```

Comment: Not really, i want to perform a specific algorithm just for the objects which implement say X and Y interfaces.

Comment: After the update, you are quite right, but your solution unfortunately involves a lot of typecasts, which is exactly what i wanted to evade :(

Comment: I've updated per your commment.  Why would you required the variable of the for each to be type casted inside the loop, it seems unnecessarily complicated (but possible).

Comment: I guess it's just not possible otherwise in C#

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do EXACTLY what you want.

Here's what you CAN do.

First, you want to only operate on types that implement `IX`, `IY`, AND `IZ`?  Then just chain together your `.OfType` methods.  `OfType` will filter the list for you:

```
foreach (var obj in objects.OfType<IX>().OfType<IY>().OfType<IZ>()) {
```

Unfortunately, `obj` will only be strongly-typed `IZ`, because there's no such thing as a type that implements all 3 interfaces.  So you still have to cast, but you're guaranteed that the cast will work:

```
foreach (var obj in objects.OfType<IX>().OfType<IY>().OfType<IZ>()) {
    ((IX)obj).DoX();
    ((IY)obj).DoY();
    ((IZ)obj).DoZ(); // Note, You could also just do obj.DoZ(), but consistency looks better.
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is how it is written ATM.

Answer (score 2):

The most concise way to avoid a lot of casting and type testing is to introduce an extension method that handles it for you.

Try this:

```
public static void DoAs<T>(this object @this, Action<T> action)
    where T : class
{
    var t = @this as T;
    if (t != null)
    {
        var a = action;
        if (a != null)
        {
            a(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I assume in your last example loop that you only want to execute the loop if the object implements both `IX` & `IZ`. So you would then write:

```
foreach(var obj in objects)
{
    obj.DoAs<IX>(x =>
        x.DoAs<IZ>(z =>
        {
            obj.DoStuff();
            x.DoX();
            z.DoZ();
        }));
}
```

Your first/middle loop doesn't need any new extension method as I think this should be simple enough:

```
foreach(var obj in objects.OfType<IX>())
{
    (obj as BaseObject).DoStuff();
    obj.DoX();
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Within DoStuff. Can you do

```
if (this is IX) { (this as IX).DoX(); }
```

... and do that for other interfaces.